What writing system are they using in "Mon Colle Knights"?
What symbols or writing system are they using in the anime, "Mon Colle Knights"?
For Example:

Is it just a made up language and writing system or is it based off of any existing language and writing system?

Sorry I already used up one of your quotas with this question, so, um, happy asking and may the force be with you on your way to obtaining the language-enthusiast badge.

@Gao - huh? What do you mean? (Confused)
